# What is it.dbline.net?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

When googling around I came across this weird stack overflow lookalike.

Is [it.dbline.net](http://it.dbline.net/) a phishing site?

Comment: Looks like a proxy

Comment: That's quite disorientating

Comment: Um... I wouldn't login... Just saying...

Comment: If that's what the front page looks like my ignored tag list works well.

Comment: @Lix that is what I thought - still I am curious on the purpose. If it was just a proxy, what is the point? Also, as it gets pretty good google-ranking I wonder if those guys actively try to outscore stack overflow (SEO).

Comment: It seems as if the questions are real, but the badges seem different

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is [it.dbline.net](http://it.dbline.net/) a phishing site?

As far as I can tell, no.

Browsing through the source code, all scripts seem to be the unaltered scripts from [cdn.sstatic.net](http://cdn.sstatic.net).

When trying to [log in](http://it.dbline.net/users/login#log-in), it opens [openid.stackexchange.com](https://openid.stackexchange.com) in an inline frame, just like the real Stack Overflow does. Because of the cross-origin policy, your login information should be  safe.

> If it was just a proxy, what is the point?

No idea. My Korean is a little rusty, but Double Line is a computer science and engineering research group. The IT subdomian somehow suggests that it's their Q&A site. Maybe they think it's funny...

Comment: Log in? Brave man!

Comment: Just in case you were serious: why not log in, @Oded? That's one of the major advantages of OpenID: other sites don't get to know your password and you're in control of what's being shared.

Answer (score 22):

It's a site full of knaves who shall be rightly punished. (Or asked nicely to remove their site by yours truly. If they refuse, they will be subject to the wrath of Michael Pryor.)

Comment: Related - http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihN3m.png

Comment: @lix Actually, not related.

Comment: @cas - burninate the posers

Comment: @Till Abby is an employee at Stack Exchange (see her profile).  [Michael Pryor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/245/michael-pryor) is the CFO.  So, I imagine she's not kidding when she says they're going to notify the other site =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I got that, thank you - my amusement was referring to using the term `a site full of knaves` which I had to look up and found quiet funny for describing a site owner acting without permission.